# save user's registration date using only SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, phpmyadmin

I know getting a user's registration date should be pretty basic using php, but I was wondering if this was possible directly through mySQL.

I use apache's phpmyadmin and when creating a new column I noticed the type `DATE` and the default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so I was wondering if it would be possible to add a type of column that automatically set the current date when a new line is created (so when a new user is registered) ?

If this possible and is there any constraints to this ?
How can I do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think it's exactly as you said. `DATE` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default. Just may be `DATETIME` is better...

Comment: Thanks for answering, indeed some of my questions were answered by chris85's link. However is it possible using only `DATE` since I don't really need the exact time and don't want it to get echo'd later in my user_profile.php ? Currently I'm getting " #1067 - Invalid default value for 'registration_date' " when trying to set the type as `DATE` and the value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Anyways thanks the help, I'll keep looking into that

Comment: You can save `TIMESTAMP` and later only select the date part: `SELECT DATE(timestamp_column)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value of the `date` column to `NOW()`

It will get the current datetime and insert into the date field.